# Asp.Net Core Web API with MongoDB.Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, mongodb-.net-driver

I have an Asp.Net Core Web API project with MongoDB.Driver.

My Startup.cs :

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            
            services.Configure<StudentDBSettings>(
                Configuration.GetSection(nameof(StudentDBSettings)));

            services.AddSingleton<IStudentDBSettings>(sp =>
                sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<StudentDBSettings>>().Value);

            services.AddSingleton<StudentService>();


            services.AddControllers()
                    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => options.UseMemberCasing());

            
        }
```

My Models:

```
public class Student
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("FirstName")]
        [JsonProperty("FirstName")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("LastName")]
        [JsonProperty("LastName")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        [JsonProperty("University")]
        public string University { get; set; }

    }

public class University
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("Name")]
        [JsonProperty("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("Address")]
        [JsonProperty("Address")]
        public string Address{ get; set; }

    }
```

My Service:

```
public class StudentService
    {
        private readonly IMongoCollection<Student> _students;

        public StudentService(IStudentDBSettings settings)
        {
            var client = new MongoClient(settings.ConnectionString);
            var database = client.GetDatabase(settings.DatabaseName);

            _students = database.GetCollection<Student>(settings.StudentCollectionName);
        }

        public List<Student> Get() =>
            _students.Find(student => true).ToList();

    }
```

My ApiController:

```
    [Route("api/students")]
    [ApiController]
    public class StudentController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly StudentService _studentService;

        public StudentController(StudentService studentService)
        {
            _studentService = studentService;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<List<Student>> Get() =>
            _studentService.Get();

    }
```

After GET request I have:

```
GET https://localhost:44305/api/students 
[
  {
     Id: "60aa490d8ad1761ee24b6f5d",
     FirstName: "Jane",
     LastName: "Doe",
     University: "60a9636ece88e21431f761fb"
  },
  {
     Id: "60aa49728ad1761ee24b6f5e",
     FirstName: "John",
     LastName: "Doe",
     University: "60a9636ece88e21431f761fb"
   }  
]
```

How can I get something like this:

```
[
  {
     Id: "60aa490d8ad1761ee24b6f5d",
     FirstName: "Jane",
     LastName: "Doe",
     University: 
              {
                Id: "60a9636ece88e21431f761fb",
                Name: "Massachusetts Institute of Technology",
                Address: "77 Massachusetts Avenue, Cambridge, MA 02139, USA"
              }
  },
  {
     Id: "60aa49728ad1761ee24b6f5e",
     FirstName: "John",
     LastName: "Doe",
     University: 
              {
                Id: "60a9636ece88e21431f761fb",
                Name: "Stanford University",
                Address: "450 Jane Stanford Way, Stanford, CA 94305–2004, USA"
              }
   }  
]
```

Usually, if I was using Entity Framework, I would use something like this in my controller to get data I need in JSON:

```
var listStudents = _context.Student.Include(c => c.University);
```

But there is no similar method that I can find for an IMongoCollection. I'm new to MongoDB and I tried finding a similar example in the documentation but couldn't find any.

Also, I was following this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mongo-app?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Again: is this [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/)?

Comment: No, it is not Entity Framework.

Comment: What I meant is that if I was using Entity Framework, to get the result I'm looking for, I would use something similar as _context.Student.Include(c => c.University). But I'm not. I'm just following the steps from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mongo-app?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio .  In this case I have _students.Find(student => true).ToList() where _students is IMongoCollection

Comment: Ah. Understood. Mongo isn't a relational database, so you'll either want to build an aggregate that does a lookup on the other table (be careful you don't max out the document size by doing so - the lookup pulls the other document into yours as an array). Alternatively you'll have to query it separately.